# New Fields Not Visible in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have Kibana 4.0.1 running on top of elasticsearch 1.4.4. It was very smooth and virtually had no setup time. Suddenly I have run into a problem.

If I add a new field in my elasticsearch index, it's not visible in fields section. I can still query on that field in discover section. But, I can't make a graph based on the new field as it's not visible in fields list.

Kibana apparently fetches `_mapping` at the time of setup and stores it in elasticsearch index named `.kibana`. Once done, it never changes that. Deleting this index should load fresh `_mapping` from elasticsearch. But I don't want to lose all the saved dashboards and visualizations.

Is there a was to force `Kibana` to load fresh `mapping` at regular interval?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes in the **settings** tab you can refresh the index. Check the yellow refresh botton in the image below.

[image]