# How to extract feature from the Elasticsearch _source to index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4

I have used logstash,elasticsearch and kibana to collect logs.
The log file is json which like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5540afc2cec7c68fc1248d78"},"agentId":"0000000BAB39A520","handler":"SUSIControl","sensorId":"/GPIO/GPIO00/Level","ts":{"$date":"2015-04-29T09:00:00.846Z"},"vHour":1}
{"_id":{"$oid":"5540afc2cec7c68fc1248d79"},"agentId":"0000000BAB39A520","handler":"SUSIControl","sensorId":"/GPIO/GPIO00/Dir","ts":{"$date":"2015-04-29T09:00:00.846Z"},"vHour":0}
```

and the code I have used in logstash:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "log"
    path => ["/home/data/1/1.json"]        
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {
    json{
        source => "message"   
     }
}
output {
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

then the output in elasticsearch is :

```
{
"_index": "logstash-2015.06.29",
"_type": "log",
"_id": "AU5AG7KahwyA2bfnpJO0",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"message": "{"_id":{"$oid":"5540afc2cec7c68fc1248d7c"},"agentId":"0000000BAB39A520","handler":"SUSIControl","sensorId":"/GPIO/GPIO05/Dir","ts":{"$date":"2015-04-29T09:00:00.846Z"},"vHour":1}",
"@version": "1",
"@timestamp": "2015-06-29T16:17:03.040Z",
"type": "log",
"host": "song-Lenovo-IdeaPad",
"path": "/home/song/soft/data/1/Average.json",
"_id": {
"$oid": "5540afc2cec7c68fc1248d7c"
},
"agentId": "0000000BAB39A520",
"handler": "SUSIControl",
"sensorId": "/GPIO/GPIO05/Dir",
"ts": {
"$date": "2015-04-29T09:00:00.846Z"
},
"vHour": 1
}
}
```

But the information in the json file all in the _source not index 
so that i can't use kibana to analysis them.

the kibana shows that Analysis is not available for object fields.
the _source is object fields

how to solve this problem?

Comment: What problem (message, etc) are you actually getting from kibana?

Comment: The kibana can't get the Attributes that in the "_source" such as "agentId","handler","sensorId".Because these attributes are not indexed.The kibana can only take indexed attributes. Kibana get the items such as"_index","_type", "_source" but cant take the attributes in the "_source".I dont know how to let kibana read these attributes in the "_source".

Comment: So the fields don't show in the list of the fields on the left side of kibana, and searching for them (handler:SUSIControl) does nothing?

Comment: Documents in _source are indexed for querying, and will be re-parsed from _source for use by kibana, from what I've experienced.

Comment: The fact that you do not see them might mean that you need to refresh the index in Kibana. If you do not know how, check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690271/new-fields-not-visible-in-kibana/29691817#29691817. You can also verify available fields by asking for the mappings of the index GET /<yourindex>/_mappings.

Comment: So it need me to do some querying in elasticsearch? The kibana seems can only analysis the things out of _source.Of cause I have refreshed the index in Kibana,but nothing changed.